# File Handling Validation

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm trying to write some code for a user creation program, where it asks for a username, password and email and prompts the user to log in. If the details they entered are written in the file specified they are allowed access, if not they are asked to enter the correct details. 
However, I can't seem to get the file validation part right as despite the details being wrong, it still allows the user access.

I've tried changing around the selection and loop as well as using 'not' to check for blank inputs but I haven't gotten it to work.

```
username = input("Enter a username: ")
password = input("Enter a password: ")
email = input("Enter an email :")

f = open("Account_Check.txt", "a")
details = (username+ " "+password+ " "+email+ "\n")

log_in = input("Would you like to log in? ")

while True:
    if log_in == ("yes"):
        print("Please enter your details.")
        u = input("What is your username? ")
        p = input("What is your password? ")
        if not u or p:
            print("Please fill in all spaces.")
            u = input("What is your username? ")
            p = input("What is your password? ")
            if u and p not in open("Account_Check.txt").read():
                print("Make sure you have entered the correct details.")
                u = input("What is your username? ")
                p = input("What is your password? ")
            else:
                print("User found. You've been logged in.")
                break
    else:
        print()
        break
    break
```

It should ask for the details entered at the beginning, confirm them and then print if access has been granted and if not ask for the correct details.

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve] from your code that demonstrates the issue. Also, nobody here knows what you did or what is in the file you mentioned. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following logic with some validations on the username, password and email fields along with code modularisation.

**Core Logic**

```
username = ""
password = ""
email = ""

def take_input():
    global username,password,email
    print("Please enter your details.")
    username = input("Enter a username:")
    password = input("Enter a password:")
    email = input("Enter an email:")


log_in = input("Would you like to log in?(yes/no) ")

while True:
    if log_in == ("yes"):
        take_input()
        if not username or not password or not email:
            print("All fields are required")
            take_input()

        for line in open("Account_Check.txt", 'r'):
            if "username" in line:
                real_username = (line.split(':')[1]).strip()
            elif "password" in line:
                real_password = (line.split(':')[1]).strip()
            elif "email" in line:
                real_email = (line.split(':')[1]).strip()

        if (username == real_username) and (password == real_password) and (email == real_email):
            print("User found. You've been logged in.")
        else:
            print("Credentials didn't matched.")
        break

    else:
        print("Okay.")
        break
```

**Credentials File : Account_Check.txt**

```
username:SV
password:SV123
email:sv@example.com
```

**Sample Run : CASE I**

```
shubhamvaishnav:PythonBootCamp$ python3 TEMP.py 
Would you like to log in?(yes/no) yes
Please enter your details.
Enter a username:SV
Enter a password:SV123
Enter an email:sv@example.com
SV SV123 sv@example.com
User found. You've been logged in.
```

**Sample Run : CASE II**

```
shubhamvaishnav:PythonBootCamp$ python3 TEMP.py 
Would you like to log in?(yes/no) no
Okay.
```

Answer (score 0):

This part does not do what you think it does:

```
if u and p not in open("Account_Check.txt").read():
```

This tests if u is truth and then checks if p is not a substring of the contents of the file.

Perhaps you are looking for the existence of a line that starts with `u + ' ' + p + ' '`:

```
if not any(l.startswith(u + ' ' + p + ' ') for l in open("Account_Check.txt")):
```

Do ensure that `u` and `p` do not have spaces in them or use some other delimiter in your file that can not appear in either usernames or passwords.